# Native Query OR DoctrineExtensions for mysql-functions

Tags: doctrine, typo3, categories, query-builder, typo3-9.x

**In general, I would like to extend the query builder to MySql functions or send nativie queries.**

I want to get all records from the sys_category_record_mm table with several categories.
For this I need the mysql function GROUP_CONCAT.

The QueryBuilder does not support this feature.
But it's possible to extend Doctrine and include mySQL functionality, such as DoctrineExtensions
https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

In symfony there is a yaml file to add new functions. Is there a way to register this in TYPO3?
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

In Doctrine 3 it is possible to write native queries.
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

**Is there a way to use native queries in TYPO3?**

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT uid_foreign, tablenames, GROUP_CONCAT(uid_local) as categories
    FROM sys_category_record_mm
    GROUP BY uid_foreign, tablenames) cat
WHERE find_in_set('2', cat.categories) 
AND (find_in_set('10', cat.categories) OR  find_in_set('5', cat.categories))
```

**OR is there another solution to retrieve records with a mandatory sys_category and a set of optional sys_categories?**

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve? Is this not possible with a JOIN?

Comment: I want to get records with different types (news, events, pages) that have categories similar to a currently viewed record. The categories do not necessarily have to match with all categories but at least with 2. So that i cant show "related" content